# My socket.io and node.js code won't work - why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I was following along with TheCodingTrain's youtube tutorial for web sockets and node.js, and I finally finished it. Everything was going like it was supposed to, until the end. I don't know if his tutorial is outdated now or what, but for some reason, the two browsers just won't connect. Can anyone show me where I went wrong?

Link to part four (Where I got stuck) youtube.com/watch?v=i6eP1Lw4gZk

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.1.js"></script>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var socket;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    background(51);

    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4289');

    socket.on('mouse', newDrawing);
}

function newDrawing() {
    fill(255, 137, 0);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    strokeWeight(3);
    ellipse(data.x, data.y, 10, 10);
}

function mouseDragged() {
    console.log('Sending: ' + mouseX + ", " + mouseY);

    var data = {
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY
    }

    socket.emit('mouse', data);

    
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    stroke(0, 255, 255);
    strokeWeight(3);
    ellipse(data.x, data.y, 10, 10);
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4289);

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("My socket server is up and running!");

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
    console.log('New connection at ' + socket.id);

    socket.on('mouse', mouseMsg);

    function mouseMsg(data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('mouse', data);
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

I'm almost absolutely sure that I followed his part one on how to get the files set up correctly, because everything went right until part four. You also might want to follow his part one and part two to download node and socket. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.broadcast.emit(...)` sends to all connected sockets EXCEPT `socket`.  So, it will not send back to the one that originated the message you're responding to.  So, if you had multiple clients connected, the other clients would see the messages.

If you intend to send it back to the originating client, then use:

```
socket.emit(...);
```

If you intend to send to all connected sockets on the top level namespace, then do:

```
io.emit(...);
```

Comment: So does that mean that my code before was only broadcasting to my original tab - basically an email that 'bounces back'? Because it wouldn't show up on any other windows.

Comment: @TheCodedMasterCubing - I've described in my answer what the three options `socket.broadcast.emit(...)`, `socket.emit(...)` and `io.emit(...)` do.  I'm not sure what part of that you don't understand.

Comment: @TheCodedMasterCubing - You might find this [socket.io emit cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/index.html) useful also.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and figure it out - but just making sure: socket.broadcast.emit sends to everyone except for the sender, socket.emit sends it only to the sender, and io.emit sends to everyone?

Comment: @TheCodedMasterCubing - Yes.

Comment: @TheCodedMasterCubing - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.